# Can we *permanently* disable April Fools jokes?

Tags: feature-request, april-fools

I have a confession: When I look up a question on Stack Overflow, it's often not for fun. It's for work, and I'm probably already slightly miffed because something didn't work, and I probably don't want somebody else's sense of humor thrust on me.

I don't like [2019's April Fool's joke](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406512/what-are-the-past-april-fools-jokes/406517#406517). It's just, meh. Fwiw, a couple of other people at work have had the same reaction.

I'd like an option to disable all April Fool's jokes. Not just this year's (I know how to turn it off), but an option in my profile that lets me preemptively opt out of them. You can even label it "I'm not fun" if you like.

Comment: Oh, I don't know.  It was easy enough to turn this one off with one click.  You want jam on that as well?  I personally find the April Fool's thing a pleasant diversion.  What I don't like is people obsessing over it endlessly on Meta.

Comment: We all hate fun, but well :-P ...

Comment: @RobertHarvey I promise not to post about it next year if I'm given an option not to see it.

Comment: And hats in December, too, please.

Comment: I just have this day marked off on calendars as a 48-hour period in which information on the Internet can be taken at negative face value.  Although I do suppose what you're looking for would be to expand on @RobertHarvey's point in which the "one click" extends to every site in the network, for those of us who bounce between four or five sites...

Comment: @Makoto _"It's somehow a funny fact, that the only day in the year people world wide won't trust any news from any media is April 1st. Each other day you can just throw to them whatever you want, and you'll always find some idiots who would take that as a fact."_  _- Mark Twain -_ :-D

Comment: @RobertHarvey Easy enough sure but still a pain to turn off as you hit other sites and as you visit them on another computer (work vs home)

Comment: Yeah, I've had to turn this off like almost a dozen times already. That's pretty annoying for something I didn't find particularly funny the first time around.

Comment: Strongly related (on the global Meta): [No preference should ever be per site and per device only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326067/no-preference-should-ever-be-per-site-and-per-device-only)

Comment: Lol, that just triggered it _again_. :-P

Comment: Yeah, disabling it is per-site. If you have a tendency to browse to a lot of "Hot Network Questions", you'll be time-traveling pretty often over the next several hours. Apparently having it separately enabled per-site is by design. There was a bug initially where it had to be disabled *per question*, but that was squashed several hours after the initial rollout.

Comment: Just don't use the internet for a day.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Why do you hate people talking about it on Meta?  It's fun and doesn't harm anyone.

Comment: @Anonymous: Perhaps corporate would take the Meta community more seriously if they didn't put so much weight on trivial issues.

Answer (score 5):

A lot of people are saying "just get over it" basically, which is not only rude but it doesn't really take into account good UX practices or accessibility issues. You can see my comment here about the accessibility issues, which are real (even if you haven't heard of them) and not just an inconvenience: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417078/3838108

But regardless of whether you are aware of accessibility issues, it's good UX to listen to feedback from your users about their experience and allow them flexibility where possible. It's how you build your brand and loyal users.

Comment: Ugh, that's much worse than my being mildly annoyed. Sorry you had to deal with that.

Comment: @yshavit I can’t comment on accessibility issues with the 2019 joke, but this answer relates to the 2022 joke, which includes a 3D glasses effect where *just looking at the screen* is enough to make some people ill (never mind trying to opt out).

Comment: To their credit, the devs did remove the 3d filter from ever being defaulted (and deprioritized it otherwise) after you called it out in the other thread.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good idea. An even better idea is to avoid forcing these jokes onto anyone to begin with.

## If users feel ill, nothing else matters

Yes, the 2022 joke included a 3D glasses effect where [*just looking at the screen* was enough to make some people feel ill](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417078/14492887). I did not feel ill, but it was unpleasant for me. Luckily, I only viewed it briefly, and on purpose, *after* figuring out how the theme chooser worked. For some people, the first they learned about the 2022 joke was when their screens displayed the 3D glasses effect; this was a big problem for some of them.

**After this, how can we trust Stack Exchange to create jokes responsibly?**

## Stack Exchange (especially Stack Overflow) is an important tool for work

That’s what the question said. But no one should need to say it. It’s obvious. The community’s desire for Stack Exchange sites to be the best Q&A sites for their topics leads them to work hard on curating high quality questions and answers, and that hard work leads people to rely on Stack Exchange sites.

**Why undo all this hard work with silly site changes that prevent people from using it?**

## You can have fun without breaking things

The [Wayforward Machine](https://wayforward.archive.org/) sounds a bit like a joke (it’s not though – it’s a warning about future censorship). It is a bit silly and, if it popped up without warning, it would be very disruptive.

It didn’t pop up without warning, though. There was a period when the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/) displayed a prominent banner about it. It was easy to access for those who wanted it and easy to avoid for those who did not want it.

**It’s not that hard. If they can do it, Stack Exchange can do it too.**

Answer (score -1):

> I have a confession: When I look up a question on Stack Overflow, it's often not for fun. It's for work, and I'm probably already slightly miffed cause something didn't work, and I probably don't want somebody else's sense of humor thrust on me.

Just find your [ZEN and how to make your working days clean from unnecessary distractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_and_the_Art_of_Motorcycle_Maintenance).

Ignore that *"funny stuff"*, I am pretty sure you're intelligible enough to identify such stuff as an april fools joke, and are given to come over it with some counter reaction.

> I understood that's a silly joke, and I don't want to see it again

opt out.

Well, that might appear to every particular SE network site you'll hit, and you'll need to opt out repeatedly (These SE april fool's joke teams are really annoying basterds).

Comment: Just to clarify: if your coworker interrupts you several times a day to tell you the same joke, you don't ask them to stop?

Comment: @yshavit that's what opting out does. it stops it. If you tell one co-worker to stop with the joke, does it stop the rest of them from doing it?

Comment: @yshavit Each site in the SE network has it's own engine, and your account's aren't served from a single one. Though the april fools jerk devs have managed to annoy you as much as possible.

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)\_/¯  I guess it's reasonable for SE to keep up its habit of a mediocre and slightly annoying joke every year, per site, per device. And imo it's reasonable for me to ask them to give me the option of saying I only ever want straight SO, and let me leave the fun stuff for reddit.

Comment: @yshavit Well, if this consoles you: We hate fun: [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284390/why-do-we-hate-fun-at-stack-exchange) [2](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/)

Comment: @KevinB I've had to opt out three times already. At work, I don't have to deal with hordes of obnoxious April Fools crap because my employer hires a lot of people on the autistic spectrum, and so April Fools jokes tend to be shut down pretty hard. But going to different SE sites and having to turn this off on each one reminds me of back when I was working in a much more hostile to me environment.

Comment: @EdGrimm sounds like a local problem

Comment: _"you're intelligible enough"_ Haha. Just so you know, "intelligible" means "able to be understood". So "you're intelligible" means "you're understandable" or "I can understand you". The word you probably wanted was "intelligent", which essentially means "smart".