# What are the past April Fools jokes?

Tags: discussion, april-fools

How long has Stack Overflow been doing April Fools' jokes?  Can someone list them along with screenshots?

Comment: A quick search reminded me of the [Retro Time Machine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382111/announcing-the-stack-overflow-time-machine) in 2019. Screenshots included. Reminded me of old AOL "You got Mail" days

Comment: [What's a StackEgg?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289032/whats-stackegg) in 2015

Comment: [so] did not yet exist in April 2008, it was only created in the Summer of 2008. It did already have its first April Fool's (the whole look and feel of the site replaced with a unicorn-inspired design, Comic Sans font, bright rainbow colors, etc.) in April 2009. So, the answer to the first question in your question is: Always.

Comment: It never gets old... **Filters....** not just for selfies anymore...

Answer (score 24):

You can find a complete list of the April Fools Day pranks pulled by Stack Overflow in the [april-fools](/questions/tagged/april-fools) tag wiki:

> ### List of April Fools Day pranks by year (and related tags)
>
> - April Fools Day **2009**: [Cornify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20477/the-fancy-and-amazing-april-fools-question)
> - April Fools Day **2010**: [Unicorn avatars](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/03/31/reminder-its-april-1st/)
> - April Fools Day **2011**: [Unicorn voting animations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85549/animations-on-up-voting)
> - April Fools Day **2012**: [Clippycorn](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127703)
> - April Fools Day **2013**: [Chat with an Expert](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174407/what-is-chat-with-an-expert)
> - April Fools Day **2014**: [Unicoins](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicoins)
> - April Fools Day **2015**: [Stackegg](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stackegg) ([stackegg](/questions/tagged/stackegg))
> - April Fools Day **2016**: [Unikong](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unikong) ([unikong](/questions/tagged/unikong))
> - April Fools Day **2017**: [Dance Dance Authentication](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/03/30/stack-overflow-unveils-next-steps-computer-security/)
>   ([dance-dance-authentication](/questions/tagged/dance-dance-authentication))
> - April Fools Day **2018**: [Quack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308564/stack-exchange-has-been-taken-over-by-a-rubber-duck)
>   ([quack-overflow](/questions/tagged/quack-overflow): [What the duck?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365370/what-the-duck))
> - April Fools Day **2019**: [Time Machine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326036/announcing-the-stack-exchange-time-machine)
>   ([time-machine](/questions/tagged/time-machine))
> - April Fools Day **2020**: A 2020 prank was [cancelled](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/27/stack-overflow-instagram-account/)
>   as a result of the COVID-19 outbreak. However, the day was used to
>   promote the rollout of the new dark mode feature on Stack Overflow.
> - April Fools Day **2021**: [The Key](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406398/)
> - April Fools Day **2022**: [Filters](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/03/31/time-to-get-on-trend-filters/)
> - April Fools Day **2023**: Cancelled due to being [deprioritized](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/423947).
>
> ---
>
> See also [the corresponding tag on Meta Stack
> Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/april-fools)

Comment: I thought ultra dark mode was the 2020 joke.

Comment: @SebastianSimon It was, although we didn't fully promote it as one. The original plan was to have ultra dark mode, and then open up the real dark mode beta. So by the time we decided not to do a prank like we normally would and instead announced the real beta, most of the work on the prank's been done so we enabled it anyway as a side joke.