# Where’s the 2023 April Fools joke?

Tags: support, april-fools

April 1st landed here 9 hours and 17 minutes ago. Where’s the fun?

Or is [this incomprehensible thing](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/03/29/from-web2-to-web3-how-developers-can-upskill-and-build-with-blockchain/?cb=1) the joke of the year?

Or did SE for some reason decide that this year, the site itself is the big joke?

Comment: Just came here for the same thing. Concerned over having not been pranked yet.

Comment: This year's April Fools joke [shipped early](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423143/a-b-testing-related-questions-within-the-answers-list-experiment-has-graduated). And just [keeps on going](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423798).

Comment: @DrewReese Maybe that is the prank…

Comment: Yeah that Web3 blog was the icing on the cake of never clicking sponsored posts again.

Comment: It seems we’re quite offended that we weren’t entitled enough to be pranked this year. So rude of SE. They made us depend on something, then pulls it away from under our feet!

Comment: @CodeCaster Don't worry. They weren't done. [Now also infecting non-sponsored posts!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/04/04/from-smalltalk-to-smart-contracts-reflecting-on-50-years-of-programming-ep-511/?cb=1) Podcasts! Enjoy this year's extended April Fools programme!

Comment: @Andreas joke's on you, I can't stand podcasts to begin with. I don't have the concentration to listen to people blabbing incoherently for longer than three minutes unless they're friends or family.

Comment: @CodeCaster Eh, what? You survive family? Teach me the art, please. I'd rather just take the transcript. Maybe that's why blockchain praise belongs to a podcast. It's blabbing with no real value. :)

Answer (score -47, accepted):

rm -rf april-fools-prank

After careful consideration and weighing several factors, we have decided not to celebrate April Fools' Day this year.

While traditionally, we have an April Fools' Day joke every year (with a few exceptions), we ultimately decided to prioritize our work on other ongoing projects and initiatives. Additionally, given the current tech industry climate, we felt that it might not be the best time for a lighthearted prank, while so many are hurting in so many different ways.

We understand that this may come as a disappointment to some who look forward to our annual April Fools' Day fun. We hope to continue celebrating April Fools' Day in the future, and we look forward to bringing you more fun in the years to come.

Comment: Haha; good one.

Comment: «while so many are hurting in so many different ways». That’s when a joke and a laugh are the most needed.

Comment: Btw, people are hurting all the time. What really changes, is who the attention is on. Why do some people’s hurting matter more to you than others? Sounds an awful lot like discrimination, and systematic racism, though well-intentioned. ;)

Comment: One question, though. Is this Dejà Vu? I feel an awful lot like I’ve had this exact interaction before. Either you’re pranking me, or the lack of a prank is making me uneasy and about to segfault.

Comment: If there isn't any April Fools prank, then what is [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387507/1088098)?

Comment: It is always April, 1st on Meta ...

Comment: A simple prank blog post would have satisfied those looking forward for a year while not placing any further burden on the dev or community teams, as that could have been written by the separate team writing blog posts.

Comment: @justANewbstandswithUkraine - That was simply a mistake on our part when we started dev work on what we had intended to be April Fool's prank. 

While the team originally planned to have an April Fools' Day joke, we ultimately decided to prioritize our work on other ongoing projects and initiatives. I apologize for any confusion this may have caused.

Comment: Wait, what is the current tech industry climate?

Comment: @ThisClark At first, I just assumed «Ukraine, maybe?», but I think [CodeCaster’s explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423946/where-s-the-2023-april-fools-joke#comment952430_423966) makes a lot more sense.

Comment: What a shame.  Even Lofi Girl was able to get a nap in on the 1st, and Stack Overflow - known for some of its more interesting April Fools' pranks - just decides not to do it.  This is just...a punch to the gut.  Sure, on paper it'll make sense to have your FTEs working on stuff that brings value, but this'll be the first year in a very, very long time where the company decided not to have a little fun in April.

Comment: @Makoto - Actually, 2020, as well.

Comment: @Philippe: 2020 gets a pass; the world was literally on fire and everyone needed to shift priorities since we didn't know what we didn't know.

Comment: There will be **always** some crisis. That's a very cheap excuse, sorry. Just say the truth, short and simple: "We don't want to spend any money on something that does not give any money back". As SO the company is business, that's fair and people should accept it.

Answer (score 15):

(responding to [Philippe's answer post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/423947/11107541))

> rm -rf april-fools-prank

I don't get it. So you made one and then decided to bin it?

> While traditionally, we have an April Fools' Day joke every year (with a few exceptions), we ultimately decided to prioritize our work on other ongoing projects and initiatives.

You could have at least reused some from prior years. I wouldn't mind that.

> Additionally, given the current tech industry climate, we felt that it might not be the best time for a lighthearted prank, while so many are hurting in so many different ways.

I can imagine some people taking this time as a productive time to sharpen up on existing skills or learn new ones. They'd find themselves on Stack Overflow. I really can't imagine such people feeling offended about the kinds of "pranks" we/you do. The "pranks" from the past two years (the only ones I've seen) were pretty tame, and were tame by design (nothing that would actually disrupt people from getting things done using the site).

Comment: _"The current tech climate"_ _probably_ means that mutibillion companies whose only purpose is to get used addicted to and invested into their platform and give them their data are now laying off staff by the thousands because they are incapable of squeezing more money from their users and investors and advertisers. That in and of itself should be enough of a joke already, but the kicker is that Stack Overflow is obviously in the same boat. They can't miss a couple dozen of hours to think of and implement a joke.

Comment: I'd argue that on some years where april fools pranks *were* done, they were not 'universally' loved, and some considered it disruptive - see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326014/what-testing-is-done-on-april-fool-pranks) and [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174639/option-to-disable-all-april-fools-easter-eggs-winter-hats-and-similar-annoying) and [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174628/do-we-want-a-2014-aprils-fool-joke). I do *like* and *was* looking forward to the april fools day joke - and not all need dev time

Comment: But I think there might have been critique either way. Perhaps saying ahead of time, especially since it got leaked might have been good

Comment: @JourneymanGeek "_on some years_" okay I probably should have said that I've only been here for 3ish years just to be clear that I have no idea what happened for ones before those :P

Comment: Well yes. And there's probably more I've forgotten about or missed.

Comment: Also recycling it kinda means you lose the "wait what?" factor. Its almost worse than not trying.

Comment: I hate April Fools, and prank culture in general. I brace myself each year to find the current year's idiocy and opt out as soon as possible. I just don't make a scene about this because the masses like this and it's usually easy enough to opt out or ignore. But still as far as I'm concerned, good riddance.

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні I feel sorry for your lack of joy and happiness! :(

Comment: If you want *one* of last years, I've been using this since then: https://github.com/miken32/frisa-lank

Comment: @Andras Deak -- Слава Україні: At least it is an annual reminder that you shouldn't believe everything you hear. Always be sceptical (but not too sceptical).

Comment: @user: [There is](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406512/what-are-the-past-april-fools-jokes) (not surprisingly) [a list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast/17205#17205).

Comment: @CodeCaster [Linus has some good tips for them](https://youtu.be/JBI1r-P4BGQ?t=211). They kinda have it coming when they hire far more people than they can sustain long-term