# Aww, snap! We’ve got Filters now

Tags: discussion, announcement, april-fools

How do you do, fellow Stackers?

If there’s anything that Stack Overflow is known for, it’s being hip to the latest trends in every field. Gaming? We created [StackEgg](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252367/335251). Security? We invented [Dance Dance Authentication](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/03/30/stack-overflow-unveils-next-steps-computer-security/). Self-guided problem solving? [Quack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308564/335251) was there for you. Programming? [The Key](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/03/31/the-key-copy-paste/) is all you need.

“*But all that’s in the past,*” you say, “*That’s, like, a century ago in Internet years.*” Don’t worry – we’re never gonna give you up or let you down as influencers. (*Wait for it...*)

Today, [we’re excited to announce](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/03/31/time-to-get-on-trend-filters/) our totally sweet new endeavor: **Filters for Stack Overflow**. (*You know that’s right.*)

We’ve got a variety of stylin’ designs for you to choose from, ranging from some classic looks all the way to the next dimension. When you see our Terminal filter, we know you’ll say "*...I’m in.*" If you’re looking at classified information on Stack Overflow, make sure you’re using the Top Secret design so others know how confidential it is. And if you’re a fan of delicious flavor, feed your craving with our [Hot Dog Stand](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-tribute-to-the-windows-31-hot-dog-stand-color-scheme/) theme. Other apps might have filters that make you *look* old – but we have filters that make you *feel* old.

I know what you’re thinking now: “*Word?! Where can I check out this epic new feature?*” Just go to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and peep the new Filters bar at the bottom of the screen – and let all our different designs rock your world. (If you want to yeet our new Filters out of your sight, you can do that, too; our regular theme is the GOAT.) Stack it your way, and feel free to show off your Filters in an answer below!

Hey, other social media sites? You just lost the game.

Comment: A bit jarring with multiple tabs between feature flags. 100% thought that I was on a StackOverflow clone website for a second. :-)

Comment: How to turn off this new feature/style?

Comment: *"our regular theme is the GOAT"* Please ensure your design team has that up on a poster in their offices for future reference. :-)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica There are [very obvious buttons](//i.stack.imgur.com/YL5cY.png) to remove this. An adblocker can be used to remove the floating button.

Comment: "Hey, other social media sites?" - I think I missed the rather important memo that we're social media now?

Comment: I'm glad this is a joke, because the "feature" is horrid. Are the new header icons part of the joke, too?

Comment: Is this feature only for today? What about tomorrow and onward?

Comment: At least they listened and added a "disable and hide the new thing" button. If only all the new features came with the same button...........

Comment: @Alejandro They've done that in the past too. It working on the first try, however, is rare.

Comment: Not sure if it's intentional but the font is totally messed up on most of them. I'd use _Terminal_ otherwise :D. _Ed_ adding font-smoothing back makes it readable

Comment: Let the "this is fun - we hate fun" battle begin! But honestly, the top secret and 3d themes are so much fun :)

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine Indeed, I'm really quite impressed with the extent of the Top Secret and 3D themes. Must have been quite a lot of work!

Comment: I thought I got hacked; WTF?! Oh, I see ... good work, fellows!

Comment: _“How do you do, fellow Stackers?”_ — I thought “Stackers” was the [term for staff](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/336813/289905).

Comment: @Phil Messed up how? They look fine to me on Chrome on Windows 10

Comment: @Clonkex Chrome 100 on macOS https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWZCR.png

Comment: All I can say is thank goodness it can be turned off without a third-party script, which instantly makes it better than most other stack "features" and re-designs that have come out recently. Why can we turn off the April Fool's joke but not any of the other jokes that have been foisted upon us in recent memory?

Comment: I love the references to the filters, "Agents J & K, Child of the ’90s, Luigi Luigi"  XD

Comment: Lemme guess. This went up at midnight UTC on April füls day.

Comment: It's still March for many of us. Admittedly I was also caught off guard. Initial thought was, "Great, another feature no one was asking for. Rabble, rabble, rabble..."

Comment: I have to say, the 3D glasses had me so angry that the first thing I did was come to meta to find a way to upvote the thread (that I was sure was going to already exist) complaining about how terrible of a design decision this was...

Comment: Would it be possible for this to default to something other than the Hotdog and 3D themes, which are legitimately hard to read? Don't get rid of them, just don't have it be the first filter applied to someone first getting here during April Fool's Day.

Comment: @BSMP From what I've gathered so far, the filter you see initially is random.

Comment: @clonkex, "Must have been quite a lot of work!", a little of which could have been put into restoring the broken functionality on legacy browsers. See my "answer".

Comment: As fun as this is, I can't help think that the design time spent making 9 different themes for Stack Overflow could've been spent giving 9 other SE sites a makeover. There's still plenty of [Yugo sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/179041) on the network.

Comment: @Robotnik All these themes are relatively rudimentary and are not necessarily meant to be well-designed. Making a _real_ theme, making it _well_, polishing it, etc. takes a lot more time.

Comment: My first thought when I first visited the site today and got the 3D filter: Aww it's April Fools' Day!

Comment: I had some eclipse glasses lying around.  I've got my monitor brightness turned all the way up, and now when using the eclipse glasses, a couple of the themes are actually very cool.

Comment: When I'm trying to debug a production server situation in the middle of the night April Fools Day just isn't ... funny.

Comment: Why are you debugging on a production server, @learning2learn? That wouldn't be fun for anyone, on any day, with any theme.

Comment: I feel like this April Fool's feature has just proved how many people don't bother researching before they ask questions. The [[tag:support]] and [[tag:discussion]] tags are just full of the people asking the same question so far. ["What's Happen? Why text Green? I switch off how?!"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZW1xT.png)

Comment: I demand a braille theme that solely conists of braille

Comment: @Larnu Plus, some of these posts have reminded me how many new users post questions about Stack Overflow on Stack Overflow _main_ rather than Meta…

Comment: SO should rather focus on their content which is what makes the site unique. I disabled the filter feature as soon as I discovered it.

Comment: How about adding a filter that fixes the glaring design issues with the new question list layout, such as making the vote count big and immediately visible again?

Comment: How much time was invested on that joke instead of investing it on something valuable?

Comment: @J... I don't see how searching the problem on Meta, which isn't part of the April Fool's joke, is affected by the joke. The Filters feature has no effect on a person's ability to check if the question, about the current look of [so], has already been asked.

Comment: so much hate on this filter feature... I don't get it.

Comment: @J... The only difference: The car is free you and don't have to pay for gas. Are you still complaining that the car isn't the way YOU want it to be?  (Seriously there is one simple button to turn the new "style" off. Have you even tried it? Or been too busy complaining about how free stuff doesn't look the way you want.)

Comment: @Enrico I've invested over a decade contributing content to this site.  This isn't Twitter.

Comment: @J... you are right. You definitely earned a seat in the senate now and the right to complain™  . Have a nice april fools day man.

Comment: @Enrico and you are complaining that other people complain? Wait...

Comment: Love the anti-anti-aliasing. Fun idea!

Comment: Love it, but needs more unicorns

Comment: I know this is an April Fools joke but I'm really digging the Windows 3.1 theme. Hits right in the *nostalgia*

Comment: these themes are cool and everything. please also bring at least dark mode of stack overflow to other stack exchange sites, if not all the filters!!

Comment: Anti-aliasing? Where's the uncle-aliasing?  This is just another sign of how put-upon men are in programming communities.

Comment: I really hope this is an april fools joke, the default skin is hideous, looks like clown vomited all over my screen

Comment: @CaptianObvious the [april-fools] tag didn't give it away?

Comment: @user4581301 come on, it's pretty obvious this is a typo :) not hard to make either

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine "@CaptianObvious the [april-fools] tag didn't give it away?" - Oh the irony?‍♂️

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine seems it wasn't Obvious enough for me lol

Comment: @Oleg No typo, but I figure if I can't be utterly absurd today, when can I?

Comment: Possible bug:  You forgot to redact the description for the type of flag in the keyboard shortcuts, e.g. graying out "needs moderator intervention", but leaving the text in the menu.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/SW7H6.png

Comment: @user4581301 even better, an intentonal one, in the spirit of the day :)

Comment: The 3d glasses filter was activated by default for me both in Chrome and Edge. Firefox looked okay. I though stackoverflow was broken because I was not wearing 3d glasses and everything looked blurry.

Comment: @CodyGray only because many thousands of dollars might be at risk... no other reason than that triviality :- |. I suppose this will seem funny in a few weeks, or 364 days from now.

Comment: I love the spirit of doing something for April Fools, but these features should be accessible. A keyboard only user has no way of even turning this feature off...

Comment: @SebastianSimon: I think Anne's comment on [Glorfindel's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336798/335251) there reflects my intent with that phrasing... :)

Comment: @Robotnik: This April Fools' prank leveraged existing Stacks theming, so most of the heavy lifting was already done from the dark and high contrast modes we’ve worked on. The good news is, we are in a better place to ship high contrast mode network-wide to improve accessibility, which we have plans to do. This work does not directly address the highly customized themes that some of our network sites have. That said, part of the additional intent for Filters was also to help find gaps in our theming implementation, which would make it easier to create future themes for network sites as needed.

Comment: (Also, bonus points to anyone who got the references I put into this announcement post.)

Comment: @MarkRansom Don’t spoil April Fools day 2023! But seriously, the AoE time zone convention has always been used on Stack Exchange.

Comment: I get the other references but I have no clue what *Digital Dimension Designers* and *3D glasses* is referring to... The SO logo in that theme looks like TikTok's logo ... so is it referring to TikTok? Does it have anything to do with https://digitaldimensiondesigns.com/? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  (Really like *Frisa Lank* btw ;)

Comment: Is there any filter that allow me to detach the header?

Comment: Let me see - you could spend time and effort developing this filter crap, but one of the best Job boards available wasn't worth the effort.

Comment: The collectives pages don't seem to be styled, but maybe that's on purpose?

Comment: @Sabito錆兎standswithUkraine: The references I'm talking about are just the ones in this post. As for what Digital Dimension Designers is referencing... It's just 3 Ds. :)

Comment: @Voldemort Yep, that's intentional.

Answer (score 100):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)
The "[Create a custom filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?edited=true)" link from the main page doesn't allow me to create a custom filter at all.

[image]

Comment: XDDDDDDD yeah definitely a bug

Comment: it took me a whiiiile. Well done, nice catch :p

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that button is used to create search filters, correct?

Comment: It takes me to the page for search filters (as in the to narrow down your search results). This might be an April Fools thing, but I don't know.

Comment: @Anye and DaCuteRacoon: I'll respond seriously – yes, that link is used to create a custom filter for the /questions page (i.e. a list of questions filtered based on certain criteria you specify). [That feature was released fully in 2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330326/335251), it seems. It has nothing to do with this April Fools' joke. (Now, back to joke mode...)

Comment: Good find on this bug, @Kaiido! We'll get our engineers to fix this critical bug at once.

Answer (score 91):

If this does end up being temporary, please keep the Frisa Lank and MariOverflow themes. I actually really, really like them and they make work that much less boring.

Comment: It's April Fool's, so it's intended to be temporary.

Comment: You beat me to it. I too want to keep the Frisa Lank theme

Comment: @Clonkex we got The Key for real, though :)

Comment: I liked the Frisa Lank one, but the margins are horribly messed up, so no, please remove this as soon as the day is over.

Comment: Seems like this should be pretty easy to apply with a userscript, no?

Comment: -1 **not enough jQuery**

Comment: They are really nice. Especially the Mario theme (fits my avatar perfectly ^^)

Comment: I created [a set of user scripts](https://github.com/DonaldDuck313/StackOverflowFilters) to bring back the filters after they're gone.

Comment: Can we keep bookface too? it's very nice imo

Comment: @JMK I share your sentiment, it's a good design, tbh.

Comment: Also bookface is great

Comment: Don't forget Windows 3.1!

Answer (score 68):

In all honesty... can we keep the Frisa Lank theme as an option? I actually quite like it :P

Comment: We need someone to save the CSS and create a userstyle, for _all_ themes.

Comment: I still have the cursor trail from the 90s theme a few years ago. Someone made it into a script for me. 

Comment: @Catija I did have to think a bit to figure out what the Frisa Lank one was supposed to be. I've never heard of Lisa Frank so it wasn't immediately obvious to me.

Comment: @Clonkex First thing I find about Lisa Frank: [Lisa Frank Is Terrible](//youtu.be/qWPiaU-W9Po) (thumbnail: “death threats, lawsuits and art theft”). That… doesn’t sound great.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I don't think anything about Lisa Frank is common knowledge beyond "those really cool TrapperKeepers and stationary", at least for folks old enough to have had TrapperKeepers as kids. If the folks at SO weren't aware of what's in that video, I'm not surprised. (Though I hope this doesn't mean a lawsuit against SO!)

Comment: Dark mode was all I cared about before it finally arrived. Now I want the bright and cheery Frisa Lank theme to stay.

Answer (score 35):

Win95 seems to be missing a more responsive interface...

[image]

Answer (score 30):

The Windows 3.1 theme is missing an important graphic:

[image]

Answer (score 27):

Please let me get rid of that annoying FILTERS button. It's often in the way, especially when editing an answer, where it masks a big part of the preview:

[image]

Comment: Can't be unseen now. 

Comment: +10 Turning this off should turn it OFF.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417059/5033247

Answer (score 19):

Reviewing *Low quality answers* with the "Top secret" filter almost makes it read like *"Top quality answers"* :D

[image]

Comment: "Top Quality Answers" this should be the new tagline XD

Comment: So Top Quality Answers is a hidden secret feature on Stack Overflow? This would explain so much!

Answer (score 17):

This has absolutely demolished me, I've started writing  an answer **before** midnight and submitted it **after** midnight. Either accidentally selected or was automatically opted in, I was left scratching my head for a while

I couldn't figure out what's wrong with markdown and how my answer did end up looking so strange. A moment later I disabled the filter, but, what's **even more hilarious**, it was only after running into [that post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416981/can-the-filter-feature-stay), when I realized that the filter is an April fool joke (yeah, I should sleep a little bit more).

[image]

Answer (score 16):

The most important question: how would Stack Overflow look with 3D filter and 3D glasses on?

[image]

Comment: Someone should post a screenshot with 3D glasses on :D

Comment: I tried a pair and, honestly, it just doesn't seem to work for me? For one, it's cluttered because the black text is still there in addition to the red/cyan that you're supposed to only see with each eye. Added `color:transparent` and that helps make it look like normal text, not as garbled, but the 3d effect is only visible for me on the bold title of the page. Anyone else having more luck, are my glasses the wrong shade of cyan compared to my monitor or so? (Edit: tried on a much better monitor, same problem.) I really like the 90s kids theme though! Guess that says something about myself :)

Comment: The anaglyphic filter was a great idea but not done correctly.  The text is less readable with glasses on.  Some of the widgets are elevated above the white background but nothing special.

Comment: It does work, (Found a pair of 3D glasses in an old DVD movie box) but discovered if I didn't have my reading glasses on, and the 3D glasses on too, didn't work.   Works best if you move (tilt?) your head left to right & back  By the way, the TikTok logo is not 3D!

Comment: It isn't done correctly.  They just duplicated the text to the left and right such that there are 3 copies of the text (black, red, and cyan).  To have a proper 3D effect, you need two copies of the text (red and cyan) with the overlap being black.

Answer (score 14):

Honestly, shame on you for the inaccessibility of this "feature" showing up automatically. Users with [dysautonomia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dysautonomia) or sensory sensitivities just had their day ruined by this 3D glasses filter because of vertigo, migraines, and meltdowns. An April Fool's prank isn't funny if it leaves a lot of your users in pain or left behind. It doesn't matter that we can turn it off; we already saw it and feel ill instantly.

Don't you have some review for accessibility, diversity, and inclusion before implementing anything, including pranks?

It has come to my attention that the default filter is randomized, as some other coworkers saw a different filter by default. At the very least, Stack Overflow should select the least intrusive/most accessible feature to be the default one to show to all users.

I could have enjoyed the prank too if it did not make me feel ill while I frantically searched for a way to turn it off. This is not just a minor annoyance to some of us-- it can cause real physical reactions.

Comment: +1 If users are in pain or feeling ill, nothing else should matter. Let’s forget everything else and just vote this answer to the top. (I am not familiar with dysautonomia, but given the [MDN advice on seizures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/Seizure_disorders), what’s written here makes sense. The MDN advice talks about putting the user in control, which SO has failed to do here.)

Comment: Thank you for sharing your concerns. Based on the feedback shared with us regarding the 3D filter, the devs removed it from the set of filters randomly displayed to users and moved it to the end of the filter selector. (Sorry for my late response; I was out of the office and unable to respond sooner.)

Comment: Further to what V2Blast said: As soon as we saw this comment, we remove 3D from the randomized filters assigned to people visiting the site and deprioritized it in the list of options. We are constantly looking for ways to make Stack Overflow a more inclusive and diverse place to be, which includes acting on feedback like this as quickly as possible. There's still a lot of work to be done, and plans in progress. Stay tuned for more from us in the coming months.

Answer (score 7):

Happy April Fools' Day!  Great job posting at 0 UTC exactly!

Comment: Whew! For a second there, I was like "WTF is this screwing up my display!?!?"

Comment: I clicked a search result link and wondered what corner of the internet I ended up on this time. There are many stackoverflow scrapers/clones/ripoffs in duckduckgo results but this beat everything! Then I noticed the domain and date, first fool of the day for me :)

Comment: How do you define "exactly"? It was 50 seconds off (with the available time resolution).

Comment: @PeterMortensen I meant rounded down to the minute, not the exact second.

Answer (score 7):

I actually like the Windows 3.1 and Bookface themes.  Too bad this is temporary.

Comment: I hope Bookface theme keeps as an alternative - it looks very good, imho.

Answer (score 6):

The best part by far is the scroll bar in the [Windows 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_3.1x) theme.

Comment: Do you mean the dropdown menus?  I'm using Firefox and don't notice any change in the scroll bar.

Comment: @Anonymous It doesn't seem to work on Firefox. Try it on Chrome for a much more... retro flavor.

Comment: @DLosc Wow, you're right, that is amazing!  Too bad these will be gone tomorrow.

Answer (score 5):

I love this feature.

I'm just quite sad I don't find my 3D glasses to see what Stack Overflow should really look like.

Also, the Hot Dog Stand seems to be made by someone that tests CSS div.

Answer (score 5):

[easter-eggs](/questions/tagged/easter-eggs)

The HTML markup of pages where Filters are available contains the following HTML comment for the curious (click on your own responsibility, let's just say the destination has something to do with what stones do):

> <!--Hello Dev! Welcome to our new Filter's bar. If you need direct access to our secret keys, please go to https://s.tk/StackOverflowSecrets. (DON'T SHARE OUTSIDE THE COMPANY)-->

Also, a `js-april-fools-2022-random-can-you-believe-they-did-it-this-way` class is part of the module JSON config.

Also also, theme selection bars are named "Smol Brain Bar SBB", "Medium Brain Popover MBP", and "Big Brain Bar BBB" respectively.

Comment: Kudos on digging those up! Nice job ;)

Answer (score 4):

Happy April Fools! I love how you managed to get the update in under 1 min 30 seconds (how long the site was down for). I was refreshing constantly waiting for the UTC clock to strike 12...

Answer (score 4):

This is amazing! Thank you all

I think a little change in some of the themes can be good. For example, in the `Bookface` theme, the color of the useful button should be different to be more visible

[image]

This is completely unclear in the `3D Glasses` and `Top Secret` themes

[image]
[image]

Comment: Keep in mind they're going to go at the end of the day...

Comment: That's the point of the Top Secret theme - votes are redacted :)

Answer (score 4):

Add this userstyle to disable.

```
.af-bar {
        visibility:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The only thing I would recommend is that, when people close the Filters toolbar at the bottom, the Filters tab that still shows on the bottom right should be much less distracting.

The Filters feature is good, and the full toolbar is good (as long as it can be closed, which it currently can).  It's just when you close the toolbar, the tab that still shows is just too big, noticeable, and distracting.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an April Fools thing and probably intended to be temporary but I genuinely kinda like some of the themes er sorry... filters and it's kinda neat. Please keep these as an option for the future, although maybe don't make it so loud about it lol

Answer (score 1):

Some of these are quite fun but I'm not sure they were meant to look *this bad*.

[image: Chrome v100 macOS]

Definitely something weird going on with that font rendering. I'm on macOS Big Sur using Chrome v100. Looks the same in Safari.

*Update: These screenshots are taken from my Full HD external monitor. It looks ok on the retina screen.*

Rendering in Firefox is definitely better though so it seems to be a Webkit problem.

[image: firefox]

Comment: Right, MacOS Catalina here... most of these filters leave the font unreadable.

Comment: Interesting looks ok on my monterey (with high-res displays, but even when downscaled to "real pixel size"). Seems like the `webkit-font-smoothing: none;` didn't work...

Comment: @Kaiido ah, I just moved the window to my retina screen and it's all nice again. Screenshots taken from my, err, _state-of-the-art_ Dell 23.6" Full HD monitor

Comment: They don't look like that on Chrome on my Windows 10 machine. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

Offf. Was a nice prank, freaked out not knowing what happened with the site until I realized it.

Tho I have one question? Why some "professionals" can't enjoy being silly for at least one day? It's not like you're working on a cancer curring machine. Be happier. ^^

Comment: _“It’s not like you’re working on a cancer [curing] machine.”_ — How can you be sure about that?

Comment: Thanks for the grammar correction :) Do you know anyone who's working on a cancer curing machine and would browse stackoverflow? 

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for giving me a huge headache... Seriously looking at it for the few seconds it took to turn it off gave me enough of a headache I had to get some Advil...

Note: The filter I got first was the 3D glasses filter.

Comment: I had the same reaction when they rolled out the new top bar. By comparison, the 3D glasses filter seemed like an improvement.

Comment: I get that you're trying to be funny...but it was really jarring having it come up when I was already frustrated because of a problem I'm trying to solve for work. Now my head hurts and my problem is still not solved. Thanks...

Comment: We all have to make allowances for April Fool's ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Mm, yeah, maybe they could have made it so that the 3D glasses one isn't the first one you can get (you have to select it). That would have annoyed me as well.

Comment: @Portaljacker Then upvote [Can we \*permanently\* disable April Fools jokes?](/q/382299/4642212).

Comment: I am not trying to be funny. Having the top bar break when I was already frustrated because of moderation issues on this site, and making it more difficult to do a job that I volunteered to do and don't get compensated for... Yeah, my head hurt, too. The problem isn't solved yet, either.

Comment: I actually got *really* nauseated with the 3d filter, it's being an hour with nausea and headache (and I am not trying to be funny...)

Comment: The nausea set in during the 2 seconds it took you to turn it off, @Gabrielle, and then lasted for over an hour?

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if it's related, but I got a "Too many requests" error from my IP address on two separate occasions last night when accessing Stack Overflow.  I wasn't doing anything particularly out of the ordinary, so I'm wondering if there's a bug in the filter implementation that's causing extra traffic that got me blocked.  Could also be completely unrelated.

Comment: The first time I loaded Stack Overflow with the filters was also quite slow. Took 10 seconds or so to load.

Answer (score -3):

Since we're toying with the layout, can we get a filter that brings back the old layout as discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375489/259995) please?

Comment: You can just hit the None icon on the very left...

Comment: @Anye - that's not what I'm talking about.

Comment: Sorry, could you please re-elaborate?

Comment: @Anye - did you look at the link in my post?

Comment: Yeah, I did see it

Comment: @Anye, so how does hitting none bring back the old layout? And by "old layout" I mean the layout that was there before they mangled it.

Answer (score -5):

You sincerely got me there. Well played.

Answer (score -6):

When I saw the UI gag/style for April 1st, the only thing that came to my mind are the UI degradations over the recent year-or-two:

- Gratuitous line spacing
- Uglifying the navbar with garish contrast
- Switch to tiny, low-readability notification bubbles for messages and reputation change
- and of course - messing up the vote and view count layout

We explained and explained why this was wrong, but to no avail. And now we're supposed to laugh at jokes and gags? I just feel sad.

Comment: I guess you can do both: express concern about degrading the UI _and_ like the jokes at the same time. Also: more time spent implementing jokes means less time spent implementing further UI degradations :)

Comment: I feel the same way. It's like rubbing salt in the wound. [It was funny before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382111/8967612); not so much now :/

Comment: Not to forget the *sticky* topbar and the associated scroll bug (e.g., back-TAB to the title field does not make it visible (if it is not already visible) - a manual scroll operation is required). That is a real usability issue.

Comment: @J... why can't one hate the UI changes and still want to have some fun on the platform once a year? We both know that the choice is "fun + bad UI or just bad UI" and not "fun or good UI"

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine I don't see how vandalizing a tool used by professionals is "fun".  It's just another unnecessary distraction.

Answer (score -7):

**I think you should keep this feature, after making it more 'polite'.**

About half of these themes are worth keeping in my opinion.  The Luigi one is my favorite.  Top Secret is good but the stamp should be moved to the margins.  I even like the Terminal one.  I would very much like to see this as a permanent option on your profile page (display preferences tab I guess).  Just make the current Dark Mode, which I have been using since it debuted, into one of the choices of alternate style.

If you really wanna go for the gusto, open it up so users can submit their own styles ala the [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/).  Maybe give out rep for styles that are accepted/used.

Comment: Where's the "impolite" part?

Comment: @CodyGray Imagine you logged into Windows and your system font was changed to Comic Sans.  Or your co-workers re-capped your keyboard.  It's deliberately provocative - it's *intending* to piss you off.  Contrast this with an easter egg, which is subtle and hides - it forces you to discover it through exploration.  This slaps you in the face - it's not subtle, it doesn't require any cleverness to discover, and it forces you to stop what you're doing, break your concentration, and figure out how to turn the damned thing off.