# Can the joke filters stay after April 1st?

Tags: feature-request, april-fools

This year, the site is celebrating April fool's day with [Aww, snap! We’ve got Filters now](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416970).

I know it's a prank, but a couple of these filters actually make reading the site easier for me. Can the filters stay in some form, after April 1st?

Comment: Moving to MSO. The filters aren't across the network.

Comment: Already discussed here: [Aww, snap! We’ve got Filters now](/a/416978/4642212).

Comment: I fear they will be removed but I guess we could use User Scripts/custom. CsS for bringing them back.

Comment: It actually scared me at first glance! I was like Stack Overflow has gone too far with the "design improvements"!

Comment: Actually, please delete all the filters except for the 3d-glasses; they're the best.

Comment: LOL! This scared me at first.. thought I clicked on the wrong google result

Comment: Strangely, the facebook one is *excellent*

Comment: Some tweaking needed but I am liking terminal.

Comment: I knew there was a reason I was holding onto these 3-D glasses.   I also have a set of disposable glasses that were given to me to watch the eclipse. Both of these glasses make a couple of the new Filters Truly Awesome!  If anyone else has 3-D or Eclipse glasses, check it out!

Comment: Nobody needs the filter feature.

Answer (score 34):

Yes please keep them. So far my favorites ones are Windows 3.1 and Terminal.

Comment: Those are also my favorites!

Comment: I think the Windows 3.1 theme is missing a trick by not processing the images to reduce their palettes and/or use dithering. But maybe that's why we like it—just a homage, not so realistic as to be usuable.

Comment: I like both of those too, the MariOverflow one is surprisingly nice too but I can understand why that theme might have to go.

Comment: Keep Hot Dog filter!!!!

Answer (score 19):

[@DonaldDuck](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4284627/donald-duck) has created userscripts for enabling these themes.

They're available on [GitHub](https://github.com/DonaldDuck313/StackOverflowFilters).

Answer (score -35):

The filters are confusing and ugly. Get rid of them.

Comment: You don't have to use them.

Comment: @DanielWalker How do I get rid of that annoying "FILTERS" button that stays on the bottom of my screen?

Comment: Okay, maybe that feature could be changed.

Comment: +1. The hot dog one is especially bad and shouldn't be the default.

Comment: The default is chosen randomly @Isaiah. And that one is supposed to be ugly. The real question is why it was literally a built-in windows 3.1 theme

Comment: @miken32 I didn't know that it is a windows 3.1 theme. Thanks

Comment: The whole site make-over is ugly IMO (i.e. not funny haha joke)

Comment: As long as they move the theme selector to somewhere less obtrusive, I see no reason why it should go. Possibly move it where you select between dark and light mode.

Comment: Obligatory reminder that disagreement is expressed with downvotes, not delete votes