# Which April Fools Filter was the most popular among users on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, statistics, april-fools

As part of [the April Fools Day 2022 prank](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416970/aww-snap-we-ve-got-filters-now), the following Filters were made available on Stack Overflow as user-selectable themes:

1. Bookface
2. Hot dog stand
3. Frisa Lank
4. MariOverflow
5. Terminal
6. Top Secret
7. Windows 3.1
8. 3D glasses

I want to know which one was the most popular. Is it possible to know which one most users chose to use? Did Stack Exchange maintain any statistics about that?

Comment: What would anyone do with this information? It's not like Stack Overflow is going to maintain multiple different themes per site.

Comment: @Makoto Curiosity.

Comment: I mean, that's the obvious sentiment, but I suppose my perspective is more along the lines of why anyone would bother tracking this information. It'd only be up for a day and the info doesn't inform anything that they want to do with the site long-term.

Comment: @Makoto Oh, if this is not information that can be easily extracted *(server side)*, then never mind!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We've just published a blog post looking back on [Filters on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416970/1478931) (our April Fools' 2022 prank) and sharing some of the more interesting data from it: [An unfiltered look back at April Fools’ 2022](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/05/12/an-unfiltered-look-back-at-2022-april-fools/)

Users were randomly defaulted to one of the themes – so most of them were loaded approximately the same total number of times (around 1.06 million times each!). Most people left whichever theme they were randomly shown enabled for a few minutes; during this initial visit, those defaulted into the Bookface or Windows 3.1 themes left them enabled the longest (around four and a half minutes each). Over 96% of users who were randomly shown the Bookface, Frisa Lank, MariOverflow, or Windows 3.1 themes left that theme enabled.

In addition, after being initially shown a random theme, users had the option to select one of the other April Fools' themes or switch back to the regular Stack Overflow theme. The vast majority of users that chose to switch from the theme they were randomly shown ultimately enabled the standard Stack Overflow theme (after all, it's a great theme, [as I said in my original announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416970/1478931)). Of the April Fools' themes, Bookface and Terminal were selected the most (over 480,000 times each). In terms of average time enabled (totaled across multiple visits), the Windows 3.1 theme was left on the longest (a little over ten minutes), followed by the Terminal theme (around nine and a half minutes).

I hope that answers your question! Depending on how you define "most popular", the Bookface and Windows 3.1 themes both did quite well.

For more interesting data on our April Fools' prank (and on the easter egg in our Filters code), [go check out the blog post here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/05/12/an-unfiltered-look-back-at-2022-april-fools/)!